# Convert output of CoGroupByKey as row to load into BigQuery using Apache Beam Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Not able to convert the output of CoGroupByKey as row to load into BQ using Beam Python.
Tried many ways but not succeeded.

The outcome of CoGroupByKey as follows:

```
(100, ([61], [49]))
(101, ([62], [41]))
```

The code I have tried is:

```
# Get Car cust_id, income
class getKV(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, lines):
        return [(int(lines[0]),int(lines[3]))]
# Get Car cust_id, score
class getKV2(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, lines):
        return [(int(lines[0]),int(lines[1]))]

class BuildRowFn(beam.DoFn):
def process(self, element):
    row = {}
    (cust_id, x) = element
    tup=()
    for e in x:
        tup = tup + tuple(e)
    (cust_income, cust_score) = tup
    row['custid'] = cust_id
    row['custincome'] = cust_income
    row['custscore'] = cust_score
    print(row)
    return row

# table_schema
new_table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
    projectId='project',
    datasetId='dataset',
    tableId='bqtable')

table_schema = 'custid:INTEGER, income:INTEGER, score:INTEGER'

# Creating a pipeline
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

cust_info = (pipeline 
| 'Cust info' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://bucket/info.csv', skip_header_lines=True)
| "Split cust info" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
| 'Get the (cust_id,income)' >> beam.ParDo(getKV())
)

cust_score = (pipeline 
| 'Cust score' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://bucket/score.csv', skip_header_lines=True)
| "Split cust score" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
| 'Get the (cust_id,score)' >> beam.ParDo(getKV2())
)

custdata = (cust_info,cust_score | 'Merge' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
)

(custdata 
| beam.ParDo(BuildRowFn())
| "WriteBQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        new_table_spec,
        schema=table_schema,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
)

# Run a pipeline
result = pipeline.run()
```

Tried different logics to convert in BuildRowFn class but not use.
Getting the error `TypeError: 'PCollection' object is not iterable`
Please suggest me how to convert that into row to load into BQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: The issue why Pcollection is not Iterable is, the bracket () is not at right place. Both PCollections should be in brackets to join.
I have corrected as

```
custdata = (
    (cust_info,cust_score) 
    | 'Merge' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()   
)
```

Issue 2: For debugging purpose I print the data just before writing into BQ. With this print, all the PCollection data got emptied hence nothing for writing into BQ.
So, I removed print statement.

It worked.